# Select distinct by unique column

Tags: sql-server, distinct-values, unique-index

For example now I have a table like this:

```
Col1      Col2  Col3    Col4
1         1     1       1
11        2     3       44
111       2     3       444
1111      3     3       3
```

I have another table with the same structure, except that it has an unique index include Col2 and Col3. So, I want to select from the first table and insert into the second table, but skip record that have the same unique index. So I can have a new table with data like:

```
Col1      Col2  Col3    Col4
1         1     1       1
11        2     3       44
1111      3     3       3
```

How can I do that ?

Currently I'm using Merge Into, but in the situation that my table have millions records it is very slow

Comment: If you truly have a unique index/constraint on (Col2, Col3) your table data is in an invalid state and you've got a bigger problem on your hands.

Comment: Records should not have the same unique index. If they do, it's not a unique index. If you simply mean that you want to select a single value for every unique Col2/Col3 combination then you will have to add what record you want to select. Just 'skipping' records is meaningless as by default, data is assumed not to be ordered in any particular way.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, without unique index/constraint -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
       Col1 VARCHAR(10)
     , Col2 VARCHAR(10)
     , Col3 VARCHAR(10)
     , Col4 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
VALUES 
     ('1',     '1', '1', '1'),
     ('11',    '2', '3', '44'),
     ('111',   '2', '3', '444'),
     ('1111',  '3', '3', '3')

SELECT
      Col1 = MIN(Col1)
    , Col2
    , Col3
    , Col4 = MIN(Col4)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY
      Col2
    , Col3
```

**Output:**

```
Col1       Col2       Col3       Col4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1          1          1          1
11         2          3          44
1111       3          3          3
```

Comment: Above data is just an example, in reality, it is varchar datatype and it also not simple as 1,2,3 like that

Comment: This would work ok varchar's too, BUT the above query could very well select data from different records. This will almost never be what you want.

Comment: Thank you, it is good enough. I want to ask you another question, if I use group by in my first table like you did, an error happen: Column 'Col1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. But if I use a temp table like in your answer, it is OK. So why was that happen?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just put `Col1` in `GROUP BY` block or add aggregate function for this column.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll be able to do much better than a merge, but you could try optimizing your merge query. Maybe post the query you are currently using? In any case, analytics tend to be fast in these case. Something along the following lines for example:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM (
    SELECT Col1,
           Col2,
           Col3,
           Col4,
           MIN(Col1) OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3) AS MinCol1
    FROM someTable
) Temp
WHERE Col1 = MinCol1
```

Comment: When I drop unique index and insert all records into new table, It only take about 1 hour to insert 22 millions records. But if I use merge into, it take me nearly 3 hour. So I feel that it is very slow :(. About this question, Devart have a good answer, but with that answer, I have to insert data into a temp table, then again insert into real table. I think that it will be slow too.

Comment: Do you have any ideal for my situation, Devart ?

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand your question @user2500561. Can you provide your query (`'Col1' is invalid`) with small record set.

Comment: Ah, your above answer is correct :). I forgot Col1=MIN(Col1). Sorry about that :)